# How to bypass Chocolatey install confirmation?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

When I want to install packages like vagrant with chocolatey, I get the message:

> The package vagrant wants to run 'chocolateyInstall.ps1'. Note: If you
>   don't run this script, the installation will fail. Do you want to run
>   the script?

Is there a way to overleap this question or something like a silent-mode?

One command for example in PowerShell:

```
choco install vagrant
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does adding `-confirm:$false` to the command line do anything for you?

Comment: I don't think that it is a duplicate question, but the answer (Parameter "- y")  is identic. Thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is really a duplicate of this question:

[How do I update all Chocolatey apps without confirmation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873439/how-do-i-update-all-chocolatey-apps-without-confirmation)

Yes, totally possible, use:

`choco install vagrant -y`

See also `choco install -h` for more information.